# Basic JDBC select working, when I switch to prepared statement it doesn't work

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using Java 8 and oracle.

I have confirmed that this code is working:

```
Statement stmt = null;

String query = "select * from custref";

stmt  = con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
         String cName = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_NAME");
         System.out.println(cName);
    }
```

When I change it to this, it does not give any results:

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;

String query = "select * from custref where CUSTOMER_NUMBER = ?";

prepStmt  = con.prepareStatement(query);
prepStmt.setString(1, "12344321");

ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String cName = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_NAME");

    System.out.println(cName);
}
```

I have confirmed that my data type is VARCHAR hence the set string.  I know my connections are fine because the basic search works just when I switch to parameterized it doesn't fail or throw exceptions it just doesn't have a result set.  I have also tried the :customerNumber convention instead of the ? and this didn't work either. This is quite embarrassing but I am at my end here, nothing I can find seems to address this.

Comment: Are you sure that there is an entry in your DB that has a CUSTOM_NUMBER = 12344321?

Comment: Great question, sorry I forgot to mention that I copy paste that exact query I am using in JDBC to Oracle and it returns a result.

Comment: It would be easier to spot the difference if the query would be the same on both sides.

Comment: Does the query in the prepared statement also work if you execute it directly against the DB? select * from custref where CUSTOMER_NUMBER  = '12344321';

Comment: Yes that is what I was saying, I do that exact query in Oracle and it returns a result in Oracle SQL developer connected to the same DB.

Comment: Sorry I know what you mean now @vlumi, no, if I hard code that to the query, same thing, no result.

Comment: String query = "select * from custref where CUSTOMER_NUMBER = '12344321'";

Comment: So if CUSTOMER_NUMBER is VARCHAR, then could the values be padded with space? You could see if it matches with LIKE: select * from custref where CUSTOMER_NUMBER LIKE '%12344321%';

Comment: @vlumi unfortunatley this did not work:  select * from custref where CUSTOMER_NUMBER like '%12344321%'

Comment: I'm sure it's a silly typo or something, but it might be easier to figure out given a simplified version of the table as DDL with a couple of INSERT statements.

Comment: I don't yet have a final resolution but I just confirmed that this is working with a different customer number.  This must be some sort of data issue and not JDBC or Java related so this can be closed. Thank you to everyone.